# Is there anything similar to AWS cloudwatch Integration in GCP

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to get cloud metrics of a service deployed in GCP for my python project but I can't find anything like boto3 library for AWS. Is there any google API to fetch metrics like CPU utilization, memory used etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Google Cloud SDK for [Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference). That is the equivalent of `boto3`.  The difference is, as you can see from the link, instead of 1 single library, Google splits it into multiple libraries based on service. For example, for logging, the library is `google-cloud-logging`.

And of course they have APIs. This [article](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) from their docs explained the cloud logging API and even mentioned which Cloud Client Library to use.